# Is the <th> tag the same as <td>?

Tags: html, css

I have a question

If i put :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="width100px"></th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`width100px` = `width: 100px`

Does `<td>` takes the same characteristics as `<th>`?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean by using inline styles then yes.

take a look :

```css
th {
  /*demo styles*/
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}
.width100px {
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<h3>CSS Classes</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="width100px"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr />
<h3>CSS  inline styles</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:100px"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr />
<h3>HTML old width tag - deprecated, don't use unless for email purposes</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th width="100"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks you ! I understand now !